# Better way for storing a lot of data?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, performance

**Hi .**
I have more than 6000 record long-length ( each record is  2 or 3 paragraph) of data in Arabic language (UTF-8) and for each row i have 12 translation in other language's . I want to write a web-application using ASP.NET  & C# .

**Questions 1:** 
What type of database is the best for this app ( MySQL,MSSQL,Sqlite,.... ) ?

**Questions 2:**
What of this Solution in better in speed , performance and easier in coding for web-app:

2-1 - One table , and all translation save as fields on that?

2-2 - One table for each translate and use relationship?

Comment: Less than 100k rows is not really "a lot", and 2-1 is not the right answer unless you need to denormalize your data, which you don't.

Comment: For question 2, I'd answer 2-3; one table with a text id, a language id and a single text field. That way, you can add languages without changing the data model or code, and you don't have to load the text in all languages to display one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two reasons why you want to use a relational model.  One is that most, if not all database engines have a limit on how much data can go into one row.  Two is that it will be easier to add more languages later on should the need arise.

If you have a choice between MySql and Sql Server, go with the one with which you are most comfortable working.  I have never used SqlLite so I am not qualified to comment on it.

Comment: 3rd reaon: databases don't like text fields rows mixed with other data.